# Do Google App Script triggers have any expiry time?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Change trigger in a Google Sheet and want to know whether a trigger has any expiration time by default?

Comment: ```````No```````

Answer (score 0):

No, the official documentation does not mention any expiry time on [Google Apps Script Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).